# Get a list of routes and params in Golang HTTP or Gorilla package

Tags: web-services, go, gorilla

When I write a simple web application like this:

```
func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Fprintf(w, "Hi there, I love %s!", r.URL.Path[1:])
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/about", handler)
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

How can I find the list of routes and params which I defined in my web app?
e.g find "/about" in this example.

**EDIT 1:**
How can get this one params and route?

```
gorilla.HandleFunc(`/check/{id:[0-9]+}`, func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    res.Write([]byte("Regexp works :)"))
})
```

Comment: What is the requirement that you're trying to solve by finding this?

Comment: With gorilla/mux: you can use [`router.Walk`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Router.Walk) to walk the router, and then call [`route.GetPathTemplate`](https://godoc.org/github.com/gorilla/mux#Route.GetPathTemplate) to get the pattern for that route.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**With Go 1.22, or when using GO 1.21 with `GODEBUG=httpmuxgo121=1`**:

You could use `http.DefaultServeMux` (type [ServeMux](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#ServeMux)) and examine it. With `reflect` package you can `ValueOf` the default multiplexer and extract `m` attribute which is a map of your routes.

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(http.DefaultServeMux).Elem()
fmt.Printf("routes: %v\n", v.FieldByName("mux121").FieldByName("m"))
```

**With Go 1.21 or below**:

You could use `http.DefaultServeMux` (type [ServeMux](https://golang.org/src/net/http/server.go?s=53067:53192#L1780)) and examine it. With `reflect` package you can `ValueOf` the default multiplexer and extract `m` attribute which is a map of your routes.

```
v := reflect.ValueOf(http.DefaultServeMux).Elem()
fmt.Printf("routes: %v\n", v.FieldByName("m"))
```

**upd**:

if you use `net/http` than you should implement extracting params before any request is actually done by yourself; otherwise you have access to params with `r.URL.Query()`

if you use `gorilla/mux` than as *elithrar* mentioned you should use `Walk`:

*func main*:

```
r := mux.NewRouter()
r.HandleFunc("/path/{param1}", handler)

err := r.Walk(gorillaWalkFn)
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}
```

*func gorillaWalkFn*:

```
func gorillaWalkFn(route *mux.Route, router *mux.Router, ancestors []*mux.Route) error {
    path, err := route.GetPathTemplate()
    return nil
}
```

the `path` variable contains your template:

"/path/{param1}"

but you should extract params manually.

Comment: Thank you but it just return a list of routes how can I return params like /:id ? Please check my question again I edited it

Comment: I've updated the answer, please, check it if it's helpful

Answer (score 3):

You can see list of routes in HTTP package.

```
http.HandleFunc("/favicon.ico", func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    http.ServeFile(res, req, "favicon.ico")
})
http.HandleFunc(`/check`, func(res http.ResponseWriter, req *http.Request) {
    res.Write([]byte("Regexp works :)"))
})

httpMux := reflect.ValueOf(http.DefaultServeMux).Elem()
finList := httpMux.FieldByIndex([]int{1})
fmt.Println(finList)
```

Answer (score 1):

An answer to improve i guess.

it provides the missing piece of code to extract parameters from the route path template string.

```golang
var pathTemplateRegex = regexp.MustCompile(`\{(\\?[^}])+\}`)

func getRouteParams(router *mux.Router, route string) []string {
    r := router.Get(route)
    if r == nil {
        return nil
    }
    t, _ := r.GetPathTemplate()
    params := pathTemplateRegex.FindAllString(t, -1)
    for i, p := range params {
        p = strings.TrimPrefix(p, "{")
        p = strings.TrimSuffix(p, "}")
        if strings.ContainsAny(p, ":") {
            p = strings.Split(p, ":")[0]
        }
        params[i] = p
    }
    return params
}
```